# Setting PivotFields.CurrentPage through VBA to a non-existent item overwrites one of the other items (no runtime error)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, overwrite

I am currently used to manage PivotTables through VBA. The core of my code depends on manually changing the Current Page of a Field of my Pivot Table and whenever I tried to set it to a Name that didn't exist in the PivotTable, it would return a runtime error.
Now, creating a new, simple sub, I am setting my Pivot Field to a list of Items but whenever one of them is not included in the Pivot Table, it overwrites the current one and the code repeats the value.
[Example of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU12p.png)

The worst part is that the Item in the Pivot Field stays overwritten, completely damaging the Pivot Table (I have to restore previous version of the document to fix it).
[There is no "Ixachi-8", but the entry was inserted in the Field, replacing Ixachi-35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddqr9.png)

[The data corresponds to Ixachi-35, but the filter now calls it only "Ixachi-8"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqqlV.png)

The code:

```
Sub qomaxs()
Dim lista As Worksheet
Dim td As Worksheet
Worksheets("Gráficos").EnableCalculation = False
Worksheets("Gráficos-seguimiento").EnableCalculation = False
On Error Resume Next
Set lista = Worksheets("Lista")
Set td = Worksheets("TD")
For i = 1 To 50
pozo = lista.Range("P" & i).Value
td.PivotTables("TablaDinámica1").PivotFields("Pozo").CurrentPage = pozo
0
pozo2 = td.Range("B7").Value
If pozo <> pozo2 Then
GoTo 0
Else
fila = td.Range("AA11").Value
qomax = td.Range("Y11").Value
fecha = td.Range("Z11").Value
est = td.Range("B" & fila).Value
lista.Range("Q" & i).Value = pozo
lista.Range("R" & i).Value = est
lista.Range("S" & i).Value = fecha
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I want to know if this issue is due to me ignoring something, or if the actual file is damaged and therefore not behaving the usual way (returning a runtime error). This is critical because data gets overwritten and if I don't look, it will lead to great errors.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` should only be used for specific lines you expect might cause an error - it's not a good idea to use it like this.

Comment: Could "on error resume next" be what forces the currentpage command to overwrite other pages?

Comment: Well what happens when you remove it?  Without knowing which line is failing, it's hard to say what the root cause of your problem is.